# USB3.0 Internal Header Connectors

Tags: usb, connector

I've been searching for a set of headers and connectors as defined in the [USB 3.0 Internal Connector and Cable Specification](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/universal-serial-bus/usb3-internal-connector-cable-specification.html) document for a casemod project.

Unfortunately, after scouring Digi-Key and a few manufacturer websites I can't seem to find any products actually advertised as suitable for this application.

Every other connector I've found so far is somewhat off in size and keying that I must be missing something in my search.

Is there such a thing as a USB 3.0 header or do I just need to keep comparing datasheets till I find something that makes sense?

[image]

Comment: Dimensions are in... Millimiters I guess?

Comment: Funnily enough, the document doesn't say but Millimetres is a safe bet.

Comment: just keep comparing datasheets   http://www.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/878315520_sd.pdf

Comment: Thanks Tony, it looks like this header is a little small compared to the standard (5mm vs 5.4 mm) which makes me think it might not accept a compliant plug without a lot of force.
The search continues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, this is a tough question. The body of plug (wire side) has 5.2 mm width, and length of 20.65 mm. None of Molex-Amphenol-etc products match it.

The connector seems to be solely manufactured by Foxconn, an old Intel ally and platform manufacturing house. There are some [re-sellers like ModDIY](https://www.moddiy.com/products/USB-3.0-19%252dPin-%7B47%7D-20%252dPin-IDC-Connector-%252d-Female.html).

Or see this [e-Bay listing](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/USB-3-0-Motherboard-front-panel-header-connector-19pin-20pin-Through-hole-solder-/171926348634) if you need few parts.

Answer (score 5):

I know this conversation is quite old, but I found it while looking for the same thing.

And since I found a valid answer elsewhere, I put it here so anyone can enjoy the information:

Amphenol G823J201240BHR is advertised as a compatible part