# USB 3.0/3.1 Header Connection Type

Tags: usb, connector, header

The standard motherboard USB 3.0 connection looks like a standard 20 pin IDC male with 1 pin missing, however IDC pin pitch is 2.54 mm but [this](https://www.moddiy.com/product_images/b/139/39463e3e1dfc4865c8571aa5af4e9209_%281%29__91497_zoom.jpg) image shows it as a 2.0 mm pitch.  Is there a name for this connection?

Also, a bonus question, does anyone manufacture a lockable variant of this connection?  Thanks

Comment: I think [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/samtec-inc/EHT-110-01-F-D-01/EHT-110-01-F-D-01-ND/6806183) is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

USB 3.0/3.1 uses "standard" 2mm male headers. Nothing special to their use for USB. They can be shrouded or unshrouded, and there are locking versions available. Check with Samtec or any other connector manufacturer. If you are trying to get USB IF certified/compliant, then there are some restrictions (color, shrouding, insert force etc.).

Older USB 2.0 connecters used 0.1"/2.54mm headers.

Comment: I'm only confused because I keep finding them in 2.0 mm spacing, like [this](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/samtec-inc/EHT-110-01-F-D-01/EHT-110-01-F-D-01-ND/6806183).

Comment: Nope, they are NOT. They are specified with a 2.0mm spacing, which is shorter than `0.1"`. See [intel spec link](https://www.intel.it/content/dam/doc/technical-specification/usb3-internal-connector-cable-specification.pdf)

Comment: This is not true. While pins are 2 mm spaced, the shroud is very special, dimensions and notches do not mate with any Molex/Amphenol/Samtec parts. The connectors are made by Foxconn, see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/348006/117785